# Independence of Random Variables $A, B$ from the Independence of $A,B+C$ and $B,C$

Tags: probability

I am trying to prove a result which I can see is feasible if I can use the following statement:

Let $A,B,C$ be random variables. If $A$ is independent of $B+C$ and $B$ is independent of $C$, then $A$ is independent of $B$ and $A$ is independent of $C$.

Would just like to confirm if this is true? Or if not, a quick counter-example? I don't wish to see a proof, so if you come up with one just let me know it's true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: $B$ and $C$ independent standard normal random variables, $A = B - C$.

Comment: What if we prescribe given distributions for A,B,C? For example, say A,B,C must all be exponential random variables. Then are independence of A,B+C and B,C enough to deduce 3-wise independence of A,B,C?

Comment: Let $B$ and $C$ be iid exponential random variables.  Then $B/(B+C)$ is uniform on $[0,1]$, and independent of $B+C$.
Let $A = \log((B+C)/B)$.  Then $A$ is exponential with rate $1$, independent of $B+C$, but not independent of $B$ or of $C$.

Comment: On the other hand, if $B$ and $C$ are discrete random variables with values in sets $\mathscr B$ and $\mathscr C$
such that the map $(b,c) \to b+c$ is one-to-one on ${\mathscr B} \times \mathscr C$, then $(B,C)$ is a function of $B+C$, and so if $A$ is independent of $B+C$ it is independent of $(B,C)$.

Comment: Brilliant! (though it doesn't look good for my original problem...) Thanks so much Robert for your super sharp insight.